# Convert String to Object name

Tags: python, object, instance

I needed help on this one. How do I convert a string into a variable/object/instance name, since I don't know how to categorize this. 
Assuming my code is:

```
a = {}
b = {}

class Test:
    def getKeys(self, var):
        return var.keys() #where var refers to the dictionary and its a string initially
```

Comment: First, you must avoid the confusing term 'variable' in Python, since objects are not variables in the common sense of memory-box

Comment: Secondly, all is object in Python and any object is an instance of a class or type. The word 'instance' is employed when the relation between the object and its class is more or less in cause.

Answer (score 9):

It's been forever since I've done anything with Python but I do remember having this problem once. I suggest you look into the [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function.

Comment: anything else other than eval, seems dangerous since if user knows much of what i am doing, the user could do sorts of things using eval.

Comment: As opposed to just pointing to a link, it would be more helpful if you could provide a quick example.

Comment: This link was helpful. Here is my code snippet as an example:     `code` def goto(self,link):

        element = 'self.'+link
        locator = eval(element)
        self.wd.find_element_by_link_text(locator).click() `code`

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, your variable `var` is a string that might be `"a"` or `"b"`. You want to use that letter to pick the correct dictionary global variable to look in.

I suggest putting your dictionaries into another dictionary, with keys you can use to look it up by name:

```
my_dicts = {"a":a, "b":b}

class Test:
    def getkeys(self, dict_name):
        return my_dicts[dict_name].keys()
```

However, this may be simply an issue of design. Instead of sending a variable name to the `getkeys` method, why not simply send the dictionary itself and use your current code?

Instead of `Test().getkeys("a")`, call `Test().getkeys(a)` (no quotation marks).

Comment: exactly what I wanted and yes, you understand correctly, thanks! +1 for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) builtin method. You'll also need an object to perform this on.

```py
obj = lambda: None # Create an empty object without needing to make a class (functions are objects)
setattr(obj, "hello", "world")
obj.hello # returns "world"
```