# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'location' - Python

Tags: python

Edit:

I am passing input through using the cmd module (currently testing it by typing `take bat`), I'm very new to python too so I apologise if that is not what people were asking in the answers.  After reading another answer elsewhere on this site I think the error may mean something like, the input is a string, not the object of the same name.  If that is the case then is there any way I can define whatever they put as an argument for "take" as the object that matches?  I am not sure how to ask that question or even if I'm using the right terminology to search for it but if someone is able to confirm that that is my problem and point me in the general direction of the answer to my second question I would gladly look myself.

The following code is split over four or so files, just to make it easier for myself to read, and it does work (just in case showing it like this makes it look like there are more problems than there are).  Right now the only part I hit an error with is the `do_take` command

---

```
import cmd
import json

def get_room(id):
    ret = None
    with open(str(id)+".json", "r") as new:
        jsontext = new.read()
        current = json.loads(jsontext)
        current["id"] = id
        ret = Room(**current)
    return ret

class Game(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)

        self.loc = get_room(1)   

    def do_take(self, item_name):
    """This is my take command, to be followed by an item name, which is giving me the error"""
        if item_name.location == self.loc.id:
            item_name.location = "backpack"
            print(item_name.location)

class Item(object):
"""This is the basic class that all items will inherit from"""
def __init__(self, itemname, defence, attack, weight, location, hidden):
    self.itemname = itemname
    self.defence = defence
    self.attack = attack
    self.weight = weight
    self.location = location
    self.hidden = hidden

bat = Item("Baseball Bat", 1, 4, 1, 1, False)
```

I am typing "take bat", which triggers do_take(etc...) to try and get the location of the item, check it against my current location (defined earlier) and then if matches, change the location of the item to "backpack"

the locations match, and when I `print(item_name.location)` I get 1 as the result, but when I try and match it I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'location'`

Any help working this out would be greatly appreciated, and this is my first post on here so I apologise if I have put something in wrong.

Comment: What are you passing in to `do_take` with `item_name`?

Comment: You might be passing in a string to `do_take`, would you mind posting some more info?

Comment: Edit your question to include an example of the code that calls `do_take` that causes the error.

Comment: Hard to tell as you haven't supplied enough information yet, but If you want to access the `location` property of an `Item` object, you need to pass the item to `do_take`, not just the `itemname`. You can then access `item.itemname` and `item.location`.

Comment: @JamGrowell we cannot tell whats wrong from this code snipped, please update question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-wording the question I managed to find another similar to mine which had the answer I needed.

[Convert String to Object name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193032/convert-string-to-object-name)

I changed my code from:

```
def do_take(self, item_name):
    if item_name.location == self.loc.id:
        item_name.location = "backpack"
        print(item_name.location)
```

To:

```
def do_take(self, item_name):
    if Item_List[item_name].location == self.loc.id:
        Item_List[item_name].location = "backpack"

Item_List = {"bat": bat, "hubcap": hubcap}
```

And now the problem is fixed.  Thank-you for your help.